# Parsing tab delimited files with Super CSV

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I am trying to parse a CSV file using Super CSV containing two fields (tab separated) with a unquoted string.

```
    occugroup_code  occugroup_name
    110000          Management Occupations  
    130000          Business and Financial Operations Occupations   
    150000          Computer and Mathematical Occupations
```

I have trouble to figure out how to configure the CsvPreference to be able to return a Map for each two. Anyone ran into this problem ?

Comment: You already tried it in any way, get an exception or anything like that?

Comment: FYI [Super CSV 2.0.0-beta-1](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/release_notes.html) is out now. It includes many bug fixes and new features (including Maven support and a new Dozer extension for mapping nested properties and arrays/Collections). And a tab-delimited preference `CsvPreference.TAB_PREFERENCE` :)

Answer (score 8):

Please try to do anything on your own next time or describe your problem more concrete.
For example:
`I try the CsvPreference.xyz but it didn't work, because I get the exception abc`

---

Some basic stuff: [CSV = Comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)
You file isn't seperated with comma or semicolon, its seperated with tabs.
So you have to create your own CsvPreference:

```
CsvPreference pref = new CsvPreference('\"', '\t', "\n");
```

Here is the full example (tested):

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("example.csv");
CsvPreference pref = new CsvPreference('\"', '\t', "\n");
ICsvMapReader reader = new CsvMapReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), pref);

List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> result;
while ((result = reader.read(new String[]{"code", "name"})) != null) {
    list.add(result);
}

for (Map<String, String> elem : list) {
    System.out.print(elem.get("code")+" | ");
    System.out.print(elem.get("name"));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

110000 | Management Occupations
130000 | Business and Financial Operations Occupations
150000 | Computer and Mathematical Occupations